# Git how to ignore specified file

Tags: git

Suppose I have a git repository with 2 branches:

- branch1

  - file.exe
  - config.xml
- branch2

  - file.exe
  - config.xml

Both of repositories contain the same files. But after running `file.exe` it overwrites `config.xml` so each branch contains its own version of this file.

If I want to `git checkout branch2` from `branch1` I get error that file `config.xml` was changed. 
I tried to ignore this file with `.gitignore` but after `git push remoteserver` it removes `config.xml` on remote server.

I tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.xml`. After this I can push to remote server although `config.xml` was changed but I still can't switch to another branch. The error: `Entry 'config.xml' not uptodate. Cannot merge.`
So my question - is there way to ignore file in local repository so I can push to remote server or switch to another brunch but not to remove this file at all? And nice option will be to push this file when I need manually.

Comment: add this file to .gitignore

Comment: @Babul He already tried that, q.v. the question.

Comment: Do you want `config.xml` to be versioned at all?  Would you consider making the file completely untracked by Git?

Comment: that means your .gitignore is not working right ?

Comment: _I tried to ignore this file with .gitignore but after git push remoteserver it removes config.xml on remote server._ - that is what is supposed to happen when you remove a file from version control. Surely, it will appear on the remote server when it runs the `file.exe`, no?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want this file will be tracked by Git but ... hmm ... manually. I want to push it to remote server manually, in all other cases I want git ignores it

Answer (score 0):

To ignore congif.xml in any path Create .gitignore and add a entry **/config.xml. To resync run

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

or

```
git rm –cached `git ls-files -i –exclude-standard`
```

then commit

Comment: Will it remove `config.xml` on remote server after `git push`?

Comment: The file may still be there on the server, but next time someone else pulls from the branch the file will not be updated.  You need to rethink your design here.

Comment: @folibis to remove it from remote server you have to delete it in local and push the commit to remote.

Comment: No, that exactly what I want, that the file will stay on the server. I'll try it later. Thanks